# How to not erase the previous list with the following in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, list, selenium, web-scraping

I tried to scrape links from several pages,  but infortunately my loop is surely wrongly done because I obtained only 25 links awith my script.

There are 25 links by page, so here I should have 75 links, I guess it erase the previous one.

Here's the link, as you cans ee, 25 links by page : [link](https://www.booking.com/searchresults.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCA0oTUIMZWx5c2Vlc3VuaW9uSA1YBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAL_5ZqEBsACAdICJDcxYjgyZmI2LTFlYWQtNGZjOS04Y2U2LTkwNTQyZjI5OWY1YtgCBOACAQ;sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3;dest_id=-1456928;dest_type=city&)

Here's my script :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait     
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By     
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

with open('links.csv', 'w') as file :
    file.write('links')

PATH = "driver\chromedriver.exe"


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1200,900")
options.add_argument('enable-logging')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH)

driver.get('https://www.booking.com/searchresults.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCA0oTUIMZWx5c2Vlc3VuaW9uSA1YBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAL_5ZqEBsACAdICJDcxYjgyZmI2LTFlYWQtNGZjOS04Y2U2LTkwNTQyZjI5OWY1YtgCBOACAQ;sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3;dest_id=-1456928;dest_type=city&')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)


cookie = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')
try:
    cookie.click()
except:
    pass

time.sleep(2)


for k in range(3):

    my_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="js-sr-hotel-link hotel_name_link url"]')

    links = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in my_elems]

    links = [link.replace('\n','') for link in links]

    next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search_results_table"]/div[4]/nav/ul/li[3]/a')
      
    next.click()

    file.close()

X = np.array(links)
print(X.shape)
```

And here's the output : `(25,)`

How can I have `(75,)` here, and 100 if I loop for 4 pages and so on ?

Comment: where you are appending the next 25 links to the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it was simple :

```
for x in range(n): #iterate over n pages

    time.sleep(3)

    my_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="js-sr-hotel-link hotel_name_link url"]')

    links = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in my_elems]

    links = [link.replace('\n','') for link in links]

    linksfinal = linksfinal + links

    time.sleep(3) 

    next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search_results_table"]/div[4]/nav/ul/li[3]/a')
      
    next.click()
```